# Vuetify v-divider vertical too long?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

[image]

I have this components,

```
<v-list-item class="paid-section-card">
            <v-list-item-content align="center">
              <v-list-item-title class="paid"
                >Belum Dikirim ></v-list-item-title
              >
            </v-list-item-content>
            <v-divider class="vertical-divider"
              vertical>
            </v-divider>
            <v-list-item-content align="center">
              <v-list-item-title class="paid"
                >Sudah Dibayar ></v-list-item-title
              >
            </v-list-item-content>
          </v-list-item>
```

and i am using v-divider vertical, but the vertical line is too long, and not adjust the height like the v-list-item,
How can i solve this problem?

Comment: Can you post it in codesandbox? so we will get more idea on the problem

Comment: Why do you need both an attribute `vertical` and a CSS class `vertical-divider` ?

Comment: @IVOGELOV i need to make line separator between Belum Dikirim ? and Sudah Diabayar, but the line way too long, is something wrong with the attribute?

Comment: More likely your CSS class may be interfering.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem as you, my solution is to adjust the **margins** of the outer container.
For example the code is as follows

```js
   <v-card
      class="mt-6 pb-6"
      elevation="0"
      outlined
    >
    <v-row>Content 1 <v-row>
<v-divider vertical></v-divider>

 <v-row>Content 2 <v-row>
    <v-card>
```